# Operational Amplifier - Virtual ground

Tags: operational-amplifier, negative-feedback, virtual-ground

[image]

In the question above I was asked to solve the general shape of Vout, and the exact values in t=0.5ms,1ms.

My question is - can I approximate a constant virtual ground in the negative input of the opamp?

From the one hand, it's an ideal opamp with negative feedback
But from the other hand, there's finite supply voltages, so it's not that simple to use the infinite gain argument (the relation Vout=A(V+ - V-) is no longer valid outside the linear regime of the opamp)

*Except the finite supply voltages, the opamp is ideal

Answer (score 2):

If the output does not saturate the op amp will be able to keep the virtual ground.

Answer (score 2):

When an ideal opamp model is used, there will be no DC offset at the output node - and the circuit will work without DC feedback. But only in this case!!